Quartic Equation solver is not working for big coefficient
Equation pattern:
ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0

Solver Code:
<?php

   function ferrariQuartic($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) {
    // Normalize the coefficients
    if ($a == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Coefficient 'a' cannot be zero for a quartic equation.");
    }

    // Step 1: Normalize the equation
    $b /= $a;
    $c /= $a;
    $d /= $a;
    $e /= $a;

    // Step 2: Substitute x = y - (b / 4)
    $p = $c - (3 * $b**2) / 8;
    $q = ($b * $d) / 2 - ($b**3) / 8 + $e;
    
    // Step 3: Solve y^4 + p*y^2 + q = 0 as a quadratic in y^2
    $D = $p**2 / 4 - $q; // Discriminant
    if ($D < 0) {
       // throw new Exception("The quartic equation has complex roots.");
    }

    // Roots for y^2
    $y2_1 = -$p / 2 + sqrt($D);
    $y2_2 = -$p / 2 - sqrt($D);
    
    // Step 4: Solve for y
    $y1 = sqrt($y2_1);
    $y2 = sqrt($y2_2);
    
    // Step 5: Back substitute to find x
    $roots = [];
    $roots[] = $y1 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = -$y1 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = $y2 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = -$y2 - ($b / 4);
    
    // Return the roots
    return array_filter($roots, function($root) {
        return is_finite($root); // Filter out any infinite or NaN values
    });
}



// Working with small coefficients
$a = 1; // Coefficient of x^4
$b = 0; // Coefficient of x^3
$c = -5; // Coefficient of x^2
$d = 0; // Coefficient of x
$e = 4; // Constant term


$roots = ferrariQuartic($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);

$lefHandSide = $a*($roots[1]**4) +  $b*($roots[1]**3)+ $c*($roots[1]**2)+$d*($roots[1]**1) + $e;
echo $lefHandSide;

?>

Here Coefficients are
// Working with small Coefficients
$a = 1; // Coefficient of x^4
$b = 0; // Coefficient of x^3
$c = -5; // Coefficient of x^2
$d = 0; // Coefficient of x
$e = 4; // Constant term

Code is working correctly.  $lefHandSide = 0 = RightHandSide
But when I put big coefficient, $lefHandSide != 0.
Example:
<?php

function ferrariQuartic($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) {
    // Normalize the coefficients
    if ($a == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Coefficient 'a' cannot be zero for a quartic equation.");
    }

    // Step 1: Normalize the equation
    $b /= $a;
    $c /= $a;
    $d /= $a;
    $e /= $a;

    // Step 2: Substitute x = y - (b / 4)
    $p = $c - (3 * $b**2) / 8;
    $q = ($b * $d) / 2 - ($b**3) / 8 + $e;
    
    // Step 3: Solve y^4 + p*y^2 + q = 0 as a quadratic in y^2
    $D = $p**2 / 4 - $q; // Discriminant
    if ($D < 0) {
       // throw new Exception("The quartic equation has complex roots.");
    }

    // Roots for y^2
    $y2_1 = -$p / 2 + sqrt($D);
    $y2_2 = -$p / 2 - sqrt($D);
    
    // Step 4: Solve for y
    $y1 = sqrt($y2_1);
    $y2 = sqrt($y2_2);
    
    // Step 5: Back substitute to find x
    $roots = [];
    $roots[] = $y1 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = -$y1 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = $y2 - ($b / 4);
    $roots[] = -$y2 - ($b / 4);
    
    // Return the roots
    return array_filter($roots, function($root) {
        return is_finite($root); // Filter out any infinite or NaN values
    });
}

$x =89565891926547004231252920425935692360644145829622209833684329913297188986597.0;
$y =12158399299693830322967808612713398636155367887041628176798871954788371653930.0; 

// Does not work with big coefficients
$a = 1; // Coefficient of x^4
$b = 0; // Coefficient of x^3
$c = -6*$x; // Coefficient of x^2
$d = -8*$y; // Coefficient of x
$e = -3*($x**2); // Constant term

$roots = ferrariQuartic($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);

$lefHandSide = $a*($roots[1]**4) +  $b*($roots[1]**3)+ $c*($roots[1]**2)+$d*($roots[1]**1) + $e;
echo $lefHandSide;


?>

Here Coefficients are
$x =89565891926547004231252920425935692360644145829622209833684329913297188986597.0;
$y =12158399299693830322967808612713398636155367887041628176798871954788371653930.0; 

// Does not work with big coefficients
$a = 1; // Coefficient of x^4
$b = 0; // Coefficient of x^3
$c = -6*$x; // Coefficient of x^2
$d = -8*$y; // Coefficient of x
$e = -3*($x**2); // Constant term

$lefHandSide = -7.7405416782585E+139 != RightHandSide. Why is it happening and how to overcome from here?

I think precision errors while calculating sqrt and exponents of large numbers is the problem. You can try libraries like GMP or BCMath for big coefficients.

but using GMP will ignore decimal part during sqrt operation

That means that BCMath is still an option. Does that work for you?

Assuming the implementation of the algorithm is correct. You might be hitting IEEE754 float precision limitations.
In which case you should use the BCMath extension, which handles arbitrary decimals. Using BCMath will be easier and faster in PHP 8.4 as it has a new class that supports operator overloading.

This is hardly an answer. It would be if you proved your assumption about float precision limitations. Also, PHP 8.4 isn't ready for production yet, but it could be very soon. Nevertheless, better stick to PHP 8.3 for now. Finally, a link in your "answer" to what will change in BCMath would have been nice.
